# Peterson's Algorithm | Context switch after turn=process

Tags: critical-section

Suppose we have two processes P0 and P1 using [Peterson's Algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0jve.png) to access a critical section.

Process P0 starts executing and sets its interested to TRUE and turn is set to 0. A context switch happens right after and process P1 starts executing. P1 sets `interested[1]=TRUE` and `turn=1`. But since process P0 is also interested, process P1 will end up in a busy waiting (caused by `interested[other]==TRUE`). Eventually a context switch back to P0 will happen but since `turn=1` it will also end up in a busy waiting (caused by `turn==process`).

`P0                     P1`        
`----------------------------------------`
     `other=1`                            
`interested[0]=TRUE`                      
     `turn=0`                             
             `CONTEXT SWITCH`             
                           `other=0`      
                      `interested[1]=TRUE`
                            `turn=1`      
                            `while()`     
                               `.`        
                               `.`        
                               `.`        
             `CONTEXT SWITCH`             
     `while()`                            
        `.`                               
        `.`                               
        `.`

Wouldn't this cause a problem since both processes are waiting and neither can access the critical section? Am I missing some details?

Comment: The `while()` in `P0` will exit immediately since `turn == 0` is false as `turn=1` has been executed by `P1`. So `P0` will enter the critical section.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm snippet you linked is wrong. Processes in Peterson's algorithm are humble. So, when P0 wants to enter critical section, it sets `interested[0] = TRUE` and `turn = 1`. Yes, it lets other process to have a turn. Similar for P1. [Here is the correct pseudocode.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm#The_algorithm)

`P0                     P1`        
`----------------------------------------`
     `other=1`                            
`interested[0]=TRUE`                      
     `turn=1`                             
             `CONTEXT SWITCH`             
                           `other=0`      
                      `interested[1]=TRUE`
                            `turn=0`      
                            `while()`     
                               `.`        
                               `.`        
                               `.`        
             `CONTEXT SWITCH`             
     `while()`                            
`P0 enters critical section`              
        `.`                               
        `.`

Comment: "The algorithm snippet you linked is wrong". I am afraid that statement is incorrect. Please check [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/98807/91753) that explains why the version in the question, which appears in textbook *Modern Operating Systems* and the version you mentioned are equivalent.